# How to get multiple values in a single input field in vf page in salesforce?

Tags: visualforce, apexinputfield

How to get multiple values in a single input field in vf page in salesfroce?

something like this `<apex:inputField value="{!LeadFValues.{!value}}" />`

Comment: what do you mean `get multiple values in a single input field ` ?

Comment: Assuming `LeadFieldValues` is a single object your format is incorrect. Once you use the `!` you do not use it again so it would be like this `{!LeadFieldValues.value}`

Comment: basically my requirement is, i have a picklist in which there are certain fields of Lead object, now once user select any fields from the picklist i want to use that selected field's api value here "{!LeadFieldValues.SELECTEDFiledApiValue}"...and this will happen at run time...

Comment: Just a wild suggestion, is it possible to use different inputField tags for the different picklist values, but display only one of them at a time based on the value of the picklist. Thanks

Comment: multiple inputField with rendered= attribute to ensure only one is visible based on prior selection is probably the VF-intended solution

Comment: Thanks Stygon & crop1645 for your help and quick reply :)     correct answer is described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following will help you

```
<apex:inputField value="{!LeadFValues[value]} "/>
```

assuming 'value' is the SELECTED Field Api Value and LeadFValues a instance of Lead object.

I have not tried this solution, but found reference to this similar to your need. so thought it will help you.

See for more information https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_sample_standard.htm